# Combine multiple pixmaps that have transparent pixels

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been trying to combine multiple pixmaps that have transparency. The problem I'm having is that there end up with strange artifacts where they cross over.

I've created an example that should show a red circle crossing over a blue circle.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PixmapIO;

public class PixmapExample extends ApplicationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void create() {

        final int width = 128;
        final int height = 128;

        final Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.SourceOver);

        pixmap.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.4f);
        pixmap.fillCircle(64, 64, 32);
        pixmap.drawPixel(45,45);

        final Pixmap otherPixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        otherPixmap.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.SourceOver);

        otherPixmap.setColor(0f, 0f, 1f, 0.4f);
        otherPixmap.fillCircle(84, 64, 32);

        pixmap.drawPixmap(otherPixmap, 0, 0);

        // Write the pixmap
        final FileHandle fileHandle = new FileHandle("pixmap_combine_example" + ".png");
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fileHandle, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image: circle crossover]

I've tried using `Pixmap.Blending.None` but this makes the second pixmap overwrite the first.

What could be causing this?